# Permanent deleting under TFS 2005

Tags: visual-studio, file-io, tfs, tfs-2005, delete-directory

How can I permanently delete a folder/file under TFS 2005 source control?

I know about the `tf destroy` command, but that only works with TFS 2008.

I also know about the [TFS PowerPack at CodePlex](http://tfspowerpack.codeplex.com/), but I want to know if there is a built-in tool to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no supported way to permanently destroy version control items other than upgrading to 2008 (or later).  Technically you could edit the database by hand, but you are extremely likely to corrupt things since the schema is trickier than it looks and [intentionally] not documented.