# How to completely delete a directory in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I have deleted a directory which contains a project solution I have added previously to TFS.

It shows a red x icon in front of it but does make it disappear.

How to completely do so (I'm on VS2005) ?

Comment: I found [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769678/permanent-deleting-under-tfs-2005) on SO which seems to indicate you're out of luck.

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked in the change?

If you have deleted the directory locally and/or within the Source Control Explorer, it will create a pending changelist for deleting.

You should see this in the "Pending Changes" section - check in the change and it will be removed.

Comment: Also, there is a setting to show deleted files, so even if it has been deleted and checked in, you may still see it.